# Drupal Commerce 2 updating with composer

Tags: 8, commerce, drush, composer

I am a retired civil servant -- NOT a developer by a long shot -- and while I have used Drupal for about 19 years, I am new to composer and drush and Drupal Commerce 2.

I was able to successfully create a Drupal commerce 2 site with the following command:

```
composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev
```

My question is this:  using composer, how do I update the project-base?  I visited the Drupal commerce wesite here:

https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/install-update/updating

and the instructions there said to use the following command:

```
composer update --with-dependencies "drupal/commerce*"
```

Is that in fact the correct means of updating the project-base?  Will Composer automatically do the updating in the correct directory ("mystore")?  And is it generally a good idea to update all dependencies at the same time?

Comment: Actually just `composer update --with-dependencies` and then `drush cr` followed by `drush updb` and finally `drush cex` when you are using config sync. Then push that and on live then it's `composer install -n --no-dev` and `drush cr` and `drush updb` and `drush cim` again.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome, thank you so much.

Comment: @leymannx: Forgot to ask: what do you mean when you say "then push that and on live"?

Comment: You always update locally first. And "live" then is your live site and the deployment process behind it. Pushing refers to version management like with Git. You `git commit` the updated composer.lock file and config and then `git push` them to your repo from where it can be pulled to the live site or your coworker's machine to run the `composer install` routine.